# How to unit test below react code using webpack

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, webpack, mocking

I have below react code and i am using webpack for unit test.

```php
export function fetchFiltersIfNeeded(filterData) {
    let sendDate = (new Date()).getTime();
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        if (shouldFetchFilters(getState(), filterData)) {
          return dispatch(fetchFilters(filterData, sendDate));
        }
    };
}
```

How do I test the function `fetchFiltersIfNeeded` ? How do I mock it ?

Comment: This is not *react code*, it is **redux**

Answer (score 0):

Use [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store) to mock the store

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])

describe('Actions', () => {
  it('fetchFiltersIfNeeded', () => {
    const store = mockStore({ /* you can put initial state here */ })
    store.dispatch(fetchFiltersIfNeeded(yourTestData))
    // store.getActions() will return an array of dispatched actions
    expect(store.getActions()[0]).to.deep.equal({ type: 'FETCH_FILTERS' })
  })
})
```